# D3 Transitions During IOS Scrolling

Tags: ios, d3.js, scroll, transition

When using D3 on IOS (tested on versions 8.1, 10.3.1, and 11.4), any transformations called after a `.transition()` within a scroll listener do are not applied until the scroll has completed. For example, if the following were inside a scroll listener function, the `height` would not be set until the scroll finished:

```
d3.select('.my-rect')
    .transition()
    .attr('height', () => {
        // assume `date` updated by scroll listener
        return myTimeScale(date);
    });
```

If I remove the `.transition()` then everything works as expected.

If I put in `console.log` statements, it's clear that the `myTimeScale(date)` is being executed on every scroll/touchmove event, but nothing changes visually until the scroll has concluded and the user lifts their finger from the screen.

A couple important things to note here:

- This is happening even when listening for both `touchmove` and `scroll` events
- This does not appear to be a problem relating to scroll inertia because nothing is updating even with a completely controlled scroll

I can work around this problem, but curious if anybody knows what is causing it.

Comment: why do you want to `transition` on mouse move (takes 1 sec), just set the attribute so the animation does not lag behind the touch position.

Comment: I use the same code to automatically scroll to parts of the page. When that happens, I use a transition with a duration. On browsers, it works just to set this duration to 0 when the user is scrolling. I can update the example if that would be helpful

Comment: the actions of a transition are done in the future (maybe the idle callback) or by `requestAnimationFrame`, setting a duration of 0 does not mean "now"